# CakePHP: Save is failing due to validation failure

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

My "User" model code

```
class User extends AppModel{
    public $validate = array(
        'username' => array(
            'username_shoud_be_unique' => array(
                'rule' => 'isUnique',
                'message' => 'Username is already taken'
            ),

            'username_cannot_be_empty' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'Usename field cannot be Empty'
            )
        ),

        'password' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'Password field cannot be Empty'
        ),


        'confirm_password' => array(
            'confirm_password_cannot_be_empty' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'Confirm Password Field cannot be Empty'
            ),

            'confirm_password_must_match_password' => array(
                'rule' => array('checkPassword'),
                'message' => 'Password and Confirm Password Field value should match'
            )
        ),

        'email' => array(
            'email_should_be_unique' => array(
                'rule' => 'isUnique',
                'message' => 'This email is already registered'
            ),

            'email_cannot_be_empty' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'Email cannot be Empty'
            )
        )
    );

    public function checkPassword(){
        if(!($this->data['User']['password'] === $this->data['User']['confirm_password'])){
            $this->invalidate('password','Password and Confirm Password Field value should match');
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

And My "UsersController.php" is

```
class UsersController extends AppController{
    public $helper = array('Html','Form','Session');
    public $components = array('Session');

    public function index(){
        if($this->request->is('post')){
            $this->User->create();
            $this->request->data['User']['ip'] = $this->request->clientIp();
            $this->request->data['User']['username_clean'] = strtolower($this->request->data['User']['username']);
            $this->request->data['User']['confirmcode'] = md5(md5($this->generateRandomString())."com.ultimate-videochat");
            if($this->User->save($this->request->data)){
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('User created Successfully'));
            } else{
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to create User'));
            }


        }
    }

    //This function is only for internal use. It's not an action.
    private function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
        $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $randomString = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
        }
        return $randomString;
    }

}
```

And my index.ctp is http://pastebin.com/DiFHLNV8

The problem is that when a user can't be saved due to data validation failure, like when a user enters a username that already exist, it throws a flash message "Unable to create user". How do I get that message only when user can't be created for some other reasons like "connection failure" or some other technical reason. For validation failure the red mark on the fields are enough.

Comment: I can't follow you? It behaves exactly as it should.

Comment: The save method will only return false on validation error so it's useless to set the flash message if the save fails excluding the validation errors case. If an SQL syntax fails or if a connection issue occurs the user will not be returned to the form page anyways to see your flash message. I would recommend leaving it the way it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply prevent the flash message setting from Controller itself.

Although I don't believe this is something good to do. What's wrong with displaying the flash message as well as the Form Error? That's more usable :)!

Anyway if you still believe you want to hide it on validation error cases here you go:

```
 if($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('User created Successfully'));
 } else {
      if (empty($this->User->validationErrors)) {
           $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to create User'));
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You must be having a statement `echo $this->Session->flash();` in your layout which shows the flash message. So remove it or wrap in a condition like:

```
if (empty($this->validationErrors)) {
  echo $this->Session->flash();
}
```

so as to not show the flash message in case of validation errors.